# How to save multiple xml files using SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I need to create multiple xml files (per row) from single query which I did. My query is generating 10,000 xml files as you know SQL Server assign different name for each xml file now I need to save them in c:\ automatically. I can see all the files but I can’t save them any advise or help will  highly be appreciated. One more hint: from SQL server we can save each xml one by one from SQL server File tab.

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.sample(
    [BTno] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [First_Name] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [Last_Name] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [BTid] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY];

insert into dbo.sample values('1B','Vartan','Sarkis','69876');
insert into dbo.sample values('2B','Anoush','Eric','87656');
insert into dbo.sample values('3B','Lucine','Arpiar','65467');
insert into dbo.sample values('4B','Anum','Noor','98076');
insert into dbo.sample values('5B','Abercio','Banninq','34897');
insert into dbo.sample values('1C','Gaea','Nishan','29841');
insert into dbo.sample values('7B','Marilyn','Vahe','78903');
insert into dbo.sample values('2Z','Bansi','Aakarshan','34905');
insert into dbo.sample values('9S','Eric','Abban','45892');
insert into dbo.sample values('12B','Dave','Tate','19994');
```

-- Here is the Query that generates multiple xml files

```
select ((select * from dbo.sample a where a.BTid = b.BTid
         for xml path('Row'),TYPE, ROOT('BT')
        )) from dbo.sample b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cheated and used someone else's function for the actual write.  Note that you'll need 'Ole Automation Procedures' enabled for the write procedure to work.  Some company security policies get a little touchy about these things being enabled.  Basically I assume if this isn't enabled, you have the ability to do so.  The write function will also overwrite files with the same filename, though that may not be relevant for your need.

```
declare @thexml xml
declare @xmlstring varchar(max)
declare @path varchar(255)
declare @filename_start varchar(100)
declare @filename varchar(100)
declare @count int

set @path='C:\testdata\'
set @filename_start = 'xmlname'
set @count = 0

declare xcursor cursor for
select ((select * from dbo.sample a where a.BTid = b.BTid
         for xml path('Row'),TYPE, ROOT('BT')
        )) from dbo.sample b

open xcursor

fetch xcursor into @thexml

while @@fetch_status <> -1 begin
  set @count = @count + 1
  set @filename = @filename_start + cast(@count as varchar) + '.xml'
  set @xmlstring = cast(@thexml as varchar(max))
  exec master.dbo.spWriteStringToFile @xmlstring,@path,@filename

  fetch xcursor into @thexml
end

deallocate xcursor
```

Enabling OLE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191188.aspx

Credit for write procedure - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Actual write procedure (must change from alter to create) - https://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try with this script, maybe will be useful:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE saveFile (@file varchar(1000), @txt VARCHAR(8000)) AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @sys_obj INT  
    DECLARE @rst INT  
    DECLARE @fID INT  

    EXECUTE @rst = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @sys_obj OUT  
    EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @sys_obj, 'FileExists', @rst OUT, @file   
    IF @rst=0   
        BEGIN     
            EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @sys_obj, 'OpenTextFile', @fID OUT,  @file, 8, 1  
            EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @fID, 'WriteLine', Null, @txt  
            EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @fID  
            EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @sys_obj  
        END
END
```

And with this line, could be save to disk a String (for example a XML):

```
EXEC saveFile @file = 'C:\test.xml', @txt = '<xml><test>123</test></xml>'
```

Here other query for save ALL your fields that returns your query:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
            select CAST(((select * from dbo.sample a where a.BTid = b.BTid
            for xml path('Row'),TYPE, ROOT('BT')
            )) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TXT from dbo.sample b
    --HERE GO YOUR QUERY
    /*Example
            SELECT  '<xml><test>111</test></xml>' AS TXT
    UNION
    SELECT  '<xml><test>222</test></xml>' AS TXT
    UNION
    SELECT  '<xml><test>333</test></xml>' AS TXT
    */
DECLARE @v_count AS INTEGER
DECLARE @v_txt AS VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @v_filename AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @v_count = 1
SET @v_txt = ''

OPEN cur FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @v_txt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @v_filename = 'C:\test' + CAST(@v_count AS VARCHAR) + '.xml'
        EXEC saveFile @file = @v_filename, @txt = @v_txt
        SET @v_count = @v_count + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @v_txt
    END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Hi Gaston, the store procedure is ok but how will it save 10,000 xml files automatically?

Comment: @AliAlisha: What do you say with automatically? if you have a SQL query, you must replace in **HERE GO YOUR QUERY**.

Comment: @AliAlisha check now, i put your query after `DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR`.

Comment: Hi Gaston, please see above Tetch answer it worked perfectly.  I also want to thank you for all your responses. Your code should work fine. Did you run the code I am getting this error: Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed

Comment: @AliAlisha: Ups sorry, i forgot convert `XML` to `VARCHAR`.  I edited the query again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gaston, I still get the error of “Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)”.  For me it's a good learning to know different ways to do the task  otherwise I already got the correct answer from our member Tetch. Thank you Gaston.